# orderBy of columns with mixed types

Tags: lodash

Can you tell how to use orderBy for objects with various field types (strings and numbers)?
For example

```
_.orderBy([{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 'a'}, {a: 1}, {a: 'c'}, {a: 'b'}], ['a'], ['asc'])
```

I've got

```
[{"a":2},{"a":3},{"a":"a"},{"a":1},{"a":"b"},{"a":"c"}]
```

but how can I get something like

```
[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3},{"a":"a"},{"a":"b"},{"a":"c"}]
```

Comment: you could use `_.sortBy` method in this way >> `_.sortBy(arr,["a"], function(item){ return typeof item.a !== 'number'})`. Where arr is your collection

Comment: @TheReason ty for direction. I used leftPad (https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad) to convert all items to string and got something like `_.orderBy([{a: '958'}, {a: 7}, {a: 'a'}, {a: '66'}, {a: 'c'}, {a: 'b'}], [(item) => leftPad(item.a, 10, 0)], ['asc'])` (I must use only _.orderBy for more complex sortings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `_.toString` results of the values.

```js
var input = [{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 'a'}, {a: 1}, {a: 'c'}, {a: 'b'}],
    output = _.sortBy(input, o => _.toString(o['a']));

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to partition according to type first, use `_.groupBy` and then sort.

```js
var input = [{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 'a'}, {a: 1}, {a: 'c'}, {a: 'b'}];
    
var output = _(input)
    .groupBy(o => typeof o['a'])
    .map(a => _.sortBy(a, 'a'))
    .flatten()
    .value();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```